# Display custom value in kendo grid column

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have an integer column in kendo grid.

```
columns.Bound(o => o.Mark).Title("Mark");
```

Mark is a nullable integer. I want to display 'absent' when the Mark value is null. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `clientTemplate` for this purpose -

First write your own JS Code -

```
<script>
  function checkMark(mark) {
    if (mark == 0 || mark == null)
      return 'absert';
    else
      return mark;
  }
</script>
```

Then at the time you bind data -

```
columns.Bound(o => o.Mark).ClientTemplate("#= checkMark(Mark) #").Title("Mark");
```